# How to have one background over another in Android View

Tags: android, background, overlay

I am trying to put a new transparent background over old one for a TextView. I am trying to achieve similar effect of game https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melimots.WordSearch.

Lets say I have a TextView with vertical blue line as the background. Now I want to have new background having horizontal purple background on top of it. But, it should show old vertical blue line as well. If I set the new background, it is replacing old one completely. Is there any way to achieve this. I wonder how this is implemented in this word search game.

Any pointer is appreciated. Please note there can be many combinations of different colors and orientations of lines. So, having separate drawable for each condition is not an option.

Comment: Did you checked [This ?](http://androiddevelopmentworld.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-put-imageview-on-another.html) It will help you.

Comment: In this example, author has used multiple ImageViews. This will create too many ImageView objects in the memory. In the word search game I referred in my original question, would have hundreds or may be thousands of ImageView objects.